# How to return True if even one word matches?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write a function which return `True` even if one **word** between the two strings matches.

`willis towers watson` and `willis singapore` -> `True` as `willis` matches

`willis towers watson` and `willis s pte ltd` -> `True` as `willis` matches

`willis towers watson` and `will tow wat` -> `False` as no `Word` matches

I unsuccessfully tried a regex:

```
bool(re.search('willis towers watson', 'willis singapore'))
```

One liner is preferable instead of a for loop.

Comment: Why use regex? Just split the strings into sets of words and check if the two sets intersect.

Comment: *"One liner is preferable instead of a for loop."* I disagree. There is no readable one-line solution for this task.

Comment: linguistically match, or just character matching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Just split the strings into sets of words and check if the two sets
>   intersect.

```
>>> a = set('willis towers watson'.split())
>>> b = 'willis singapore'
>>> any(v in a for v in b.split()) 
True
```

Alternatively,

```
>>> not a.isdisjoint(b.split())
True
```

Comment: Psst: There's also [`set.isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint)

Comment: The alternative (edit: meaning `set.intersection`) is not lazy, so I would prefer using `any`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey thanks, I legit did not know that existed!

Comment: If `b` is also a set, e.g. `b = set('willis singapore'.split())`, then the intersection is simply `a & b` and the check `if a & b: ...` Not sure, however, if this is faster than `isdisjoint`, but it would be the intersection check for two sets.